# cannot find JAVA_HOME Pseudo-Distributed Mode CDH3 single Node CENTOS 6

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I am trying to install CDH3 to setup a VM for accumulo prototyping.

There are no issues in standalone mode and the test program works in both cases.

I am using CDH3 because there are compatibility issues with accumulo 1.4.3 and CDH4.

It is my limited understanding that in Pseudo-Distributed Mode both hadoop and  zookeeper will start. I tried to run the following command and got the following error:

```
 for service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-*
 > do
 > sudo $service start
 > done
  +======================================================================+
   |      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
   |       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
   |                                                                      |
   | Hadoop requires Java 1.6 or later.                                   |
   | NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
   |       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
   +======================================================================+
   ....
   [root@localhost tmp]# cd ..
   [root@localhost /]# $JAVA_HOME 
   $JAVA_HOME
   bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64: is a directory
```

As you can see I have set `JAVA_HOME`.

It is set in my `/etc/profile` as:

```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Please tell me if this mode runs zookeeper.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CDH3 is specifically looking for Sun or (now) Oracle Java, while it looks like you have OpenJDK installed. You can download the Oracle JDK from the link that the error message provides, or here is a more [direct link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) that goes to the appropriate Oracle page.

You should note that CDH3 is end-of-life and the current release is CDH4.